# Why does this causes an error?

Tags: php

i have this codeline....

```
define('CSV_TEXTSIGN', '');

$var = ( empty( trim( CSV_TEXTSIGN ) ) ? '"' : CSV_TEXTSIGN );
```

this causes a error

```
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in... line XX
```

but there are only valid functions...

```
bool empty ( mixed $var )
string trim ( string $str [, string $charlist ] )
```

i tried to switch " with ' in define and also use vars instead of constants

am i blind ?
can someone explain me whats going wrong ?

Comment: not really the same.. it's the same error but not really my problem... it's the trim combined with empty. the "duplicate" is handling from empty and sayes non about trim ^^

Comment: That answer was #1 on google when the error message was searched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://php.net/empty

Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

Comment: omg... this is what you get when you sitting 8h infront of code... you will forgett to read the USEFUL comments and hints !! :D THX...

Answer (score 3):

From the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) :

> `Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.`

So your code may look like :

```
$var = (!trim(CSV_TEXTSIGN) ? '"' : CSV_TEXTSIGN );
```

OR :

```
$trimed = trim(CSV_TEXTSIGN);
$var = empty($trimed) ? '"' : CSV_TEXTSIGN;
```

Answer (score 1):

Empty isn't actually a function - it's a language construct (similar to echo). Because of this, PHP parses it differently. Empty() only accepts a variable as an argument. Read more about language constructs [here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php)

So, to answer your question, do something like this:

```
define('CSV_TEXTSIGN', '"');
$trimmedVal = trim( CSV_TEXTSIGN );

$var = ( empty( $trimmedVal ) ? '"' : CSV_TEXTSIGN );
```